# How to make edits in Windows to files on a linux server?

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, smb, cross-platform

I have an SMB connection to an Ubuntu Server 12.10 host that has shell scripts and config files I want to edit with a Windows 7 client using Notepad++. I am able to open the files and make changes, but as soon as I save them, with no changes to the character encoding, they become unreadable on the host.

How can I edit and save the files in Windows 7 so they can be read and executed in Ubuntu Server 12.10?

Comment: What does 'unreadable' mean?

Comment: @terdon It means the Tomcat server using the config files stops working.

Comment: OK, see Jim's answer then. Or mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** You can enable Unix line termination in Notepad++ in Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Unix Format.

One of the most common problems with text file compatibility between Unix and Windows systems is that Windows' notion of line termination is CRLF (carriage-return + linefeed, ascii 13 and 10), while Unix uses just LF (10).  This is probably getting you an error like `./foo.sh: bad interpreter: /bin/sh^M: no such file or directory`.

There's a utility called `dos2unix` that will convert any existing files for you, on the Ubuntu side:

```
apt-get install dos2unix
dos2unix myscript.sh
```

That modifies the file in-place to strip out the CRs.

Answer (score 0):

As Jim said, the problem is probably line termination. You can fix this on the Linux server by running this command on your modified files:

```
sed -i 'N;s/\r\n/\n/g' file
```

Comment: Jim's response helped me, but I'll keep this in mind in case I ever find myself without access to either of the solutions he gave me.

Comment: Just to clarify, he gave you one solution. The first command just installs the necessary program, you will only need to run it once.